# Getting time in PM or AM from a datetime string

Tags: javascript

I have a `dateTime` string: `"2022-02-03T18:40:00.000Z"`
I want to convert this into 6:40 PM. How would I go about doing something like that?

Comment: See this MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

Answer (score 0):

I would usually recommend using a date library for date manipulation and formatting, but this can be done quite easily without one as well.

```js
const date = new Date("2022-02-03T18:40:00.000Z");

const convert = (date) => {
  const str = (date.getHours() < 12 || date.getHours() === 24) ? "AM" : "PM";
  const hours = date.getHours() % 12 || 12;
  return `${hours}:${date.getMinutes()}${str}`;
}


console.log(convert(date));
```

or using `toLocaleString` with en-us formatting.

```js
const date = new Date("2022-02-03T18:40:00.000Z");

const convert = (date) => {
   return date.toLocaleTimeString(
    'en-US',
    {timeZone: 'UTC', hour12: true, hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'}
  );
}

console.log(convert(date));
```